# Total time to HH:MM:SS in RDLC

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, rdlc

this is the code i have right now. This code computes the total time in my rdlc using expressions.

```
 System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(system.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!Number_of_Hours.Value)))
```

this code shows days,hours and minutes.

What I want to see is this

113:37:00

How can I achieve it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `TimeSpan` doesn't support such formatting (output total hours), so you have to do it manually:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(113, 37, 0);
string s = string.Format(@"{0}:{1:mm\:ss}", (int)ts.TotalHours, ts);
```

Comment: @20131620 I don't know RDLC, but I think you have to do something like `((Int32)System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(System.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!Number_of_Hours.Value))).TotalHours).ToString() & ":" & System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(System.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!Number_of_Hours.Value))).ToString("mm\:ss")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this , You have to add this expression in your report
=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!DurationTime.Value)))